# How do I connect to my PhPMyAdmin database through pymysql?

Tags: phpmyadmin, pymysql

I'm new to using phpMyAdmin and am trying to connect to a database through my computer using pymysql. The phpMyAdmin was set up by someone else, but I was given root user access so I can check/reconfigure whatever I need.

In addition to my code not working, I'm confused about why phpMyAdmin says host:localhost when I have to connect to go to **someIPAddress**/phpMyAdmin in the browser to see it?

I've installed pymysql and installed it using pip. Logging in through the web interface works fine. I've set up my variables like so :

```
DB_SERVER = 'localhost' # I have also tried 127.0.0.1 and the IP 
# address I use to login in
DB_USER = myUserName # I have also tried myUserName@localhost
DB_PASS = myPassword
DB = myDatabase
```

and my code for logging in is

```
con=pymysql.connect(host=db_config.DB_SERVER,
                        user=db_config.DB_USER,
                        password=db_config.DB_PASS,
                        database=db_config.DB,
                        port=3306)
```

.

When I run my code as shown above (with the comments kept as they are), I get an Operational Error from pymysql: _(2003, "cannot connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'(([Errno 61] Connection refused)").

If I change the host to the IP address, I get the same error.The same is true for when I change *localhost* to *127.0.0.1*.

I used to get an error with code 1045 but for some reason no longer get that, and I don't remember what I did for that to change. I may have blindly copy pasted one too many lines from the Internet. : )

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a web frontend to query MySQL. You don't connect to phpMyAdmin from Python, you should connect to the MySQL server.

Comment: Thank you! Your comment gave me the necessary insight to understand the problem - I searched for a library to connect to my specific database, rewrote my code to use the mysql.connector library and it worked. =)